# How do I access the player's score after the round is over?

Tags: c#, monogame

I am a fairly new programmer trying to make a pretty simple game by using MonoGame in C#. My problem is that I want to access the player's score after the player has died, but I'm not sure how to do that. It's this line in particular I'm struggling with: `if (highscore.EnterUpdate(gameTime, player.Points))` `//'player.Points' is my guess on how I access the points the player got in the game, but it's probably supposed to be something else.` I want to access the points because then I can add them to my highscore list.

When running the game I get the error message:
*"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'
'player' was null."*, on the line mentioned above, `player.Points`.

I would appreciate help! *(I don't know if all code below is relevant to solving this problem, but I've tried my best. Perhaps you need more?)*

```
//File name: Game1.cs

    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        HighScore highscore;
        Player player;

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            switch (GameElements.currentState)
            {
                //...
                    switch (currentState)
                    {
                        case State.EnterHighScore:
                            if (highscore.EnterUpdate(gameTime, player.Points)) //here
                                currentState = State.PrintHighScore;
                            break;
                        default:
                            //...
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
//File name: GameElements.cs
//Example

            foreach(GoldCoin gc in goldCoins.ToList()) //everytime the player collides with a coin
            {
                if (gc.IsAlive)
                {
                    gc.Update(gameTime);
                    if (gc.CheckCollision(player))
                    {
                        goldCoins.Remove(gc);
                        player.Points++; //the score increases when you collect a coin, because of this i assumed 'player.Points' was to be used in the code above.
                    }
                }
                else goldCoins.Remove(gc);
            }
```

```
//File name: Player.cs
    public class Player : PhysicalObject
    {
        int points = 0;
        //...
        public int Points //here, I assumed I could get the total score from this property?
        {
            get { return points; }
            set { points = value; }
        }
    }
```

```
//File name: HighScore.cs

class HSItem //might not be relevant, HSItem contains data about a person in the highscore list
{
    string name;
    int points;

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }

    public int Points { get { return points; } set { points = value; } }

    public HSItem(string name, int points)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
    }
}
//...
    void Add(int points) //here, is called from EnterUpdate()
    {
        HSItem temp = new HSItem(name, points);
        highscore.Add(temp); //Add() in this case belongs to List
        Sort();

        if (highscore.Count > maxInList)
        {
            highscore.RemoveAt(maxInList);
        }
    }

    public bool EnterUpdate(GameTime gameTime, int points) //here, 
    { 
        char[] key = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
                       'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',  'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
                       'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

        if (CheckKey(Keys.Down, gameTime))
        {
            key_index++;
            if (key_index >= key.Length)
                key_index = 0;
        }

        if (CheckKey(Keys.Up, gameTime))
        {
            key_index--;
            if (key_index <= 0)
                key_index = key.Length - 1;
        }

        if (CheckKey(Keys.Enter, gameTime))
        {
            name += key[key_index].ToString();
            if (name.Length == 3)
            {
                Add(points); //here
                name = "";
                currentChar = "";
                key_index = 0;
                return true;
            }
        }
        currentChar = key[key_index].ToString();
        return false;
    }
//...
```

Comment: I dont know Monogame, but you'll need to pass the player object from GameElements to your Game object(variable `gc`), maybe at the time of creation via the constructor or something if the framework Monogame allows.

Comment: Did you ever assign `Game1.player`? Variables in C# will have a default value unless you explicitly assign to them - classes will be assigned `null` by default. You need to call `player = new Player()` somewhere before accessing `player` if you haven't already.

Comment: @SamBloomberg This sounds like a good answer to me, would you mind posting it as one?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've assigned `Game1.player` somewhere in your code. Variables in C# have a default value until you explicitly assign to them, and for classes the default is `null`. You need to call `player = new Player()` somewhere before you accessing `player` if you haven't already.